# ОШИБКА: функция crosstab(unknown) не существует

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Еле разобралась с PIVOT в ms sql, а на Postgre, оказалось, что PIVOT функции вообще не существует, а есть CROSSTAB. Погуглила, информация как обычно не явно понятная.

Ввожу в формате:

```
    select * from
    crosstab('{запрос}') 
    as ({название_столбца тип})
```

выходит ошибка:

```
ОШИБКА:  функция crosstab(unknown) не существует
LINE 2:   FROM crosstab(
               ^
HINT:  Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.

********** Ошибка **********

ОШИБКА: функция crosstab(unknown) не существует
SQL-состояние: 42883
Подсказка: Функция с данными именем и типами аргументов не найдена. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.
Символ: 19
```

пробовала вводить и так, но итог тот же:

```
    select * from
    crosstab($${запрос}$$) 
    as ({название_столбца тип})
```

Comment: Явно указала тип "text", но ошибка та же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `crosstab` относится к расширению [`tablefunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html). Это `contrib` расширение обычно поставляемое вместо с СУБД, но не включено по-умолчанию.

Вам необходимо загрузить расширение в нужной базе запросом

```
create extension tablefunc;
```

Если СУБД ответит, что такого расширения нет - значит у вас не установлены `contrib` расширения и их необходимо доустановить.

Comment: Уи, получилось! Спасибо большое! Теперь уже с другой ошибкой буду бороться ;Р